TV Show where the hero would shrink into computer and fight viruses
I have wondered about this for years, and so my memory is a little flaky on this now, but here goes:
This was a TV show, aimed at children/teenagers, on British TV around 1997 (I doubt it was a British made show though).  It actually used to air right before Power Rangers around 3PM, possibly on Sky 1 (I did try looking up historical TV guides a few years ago but couldn't find anything).
So from what I remember, every episode the hero (a kid at his computer i think?) would somehow find out about a computer virus and would shrink/enter his computer, and basically end up in some techie, motherboard looking environment.
Whatever foe it was (a particular virus for instance), would be there and it basically played out like the boss fights from Power Rangers, or the black and white godzilla films (The virus would even look like godzilla/monster).  Pretty sure it was live-action, and they would fight, crash into capacitors/memory chips/etc until the hero won.
The hero might have transformed into something to fight the virus (Like armour/half machine), I really can't remember now.
It is very similar to Power Rangers in terms of the fights, but it was a separate show that would air before PR and was focused around computers/technology.
I think that's about all I remember, but let me know if there are any other key facts that could help.

This one (Superhuman Samurai Syber-Squad)?

YES!  Thank you...wow, wish I'd asked this years ago!
